# how to change picture depend on language in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

**Hello there.**

I want to help me . I am a beginner in programming android Studio.
I want to pass a "specific picture" in Android Studio, According to the default language of the phone.

Example: I have two pictures, picture 1: it has Arabic writing. Picture 2: It has English writting .

**Q . I want to use the conditionals "if" and "else if" in the statement?**

*EX : if(the language is Arabic){pass the picture 1 } else if(the language is English){pass the picture 2 }.....and so on to multiple languages.*

- Please, I want an answer to this algorithm.

Comment: this isn't an algorithm, this is, as you yourself suggest an 'if else conditional block'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this:

First way, using `switch` and `case` ( more efficient ):

```
yourImageViewID.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_for_other_languages);
switch(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()) {
    case "ar": {
        //"ar" is the code of the Arabic language
         
    yourImageViewID.setImageResource(R.drawable.arabic_image);
        break;
    }
    case "en": {
        //"en" is the code of the English language
        
    yourImageViewID.setImageResource(R.drawable.english_image);
        break;
    }
}
```

Second way, using `if else` ( less efficient ):

```
yourImageViewID.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_for_other_languages);
if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar")) {
    yourImageViewID.setImageResource(R.drawable.arabic_image);
}
else if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("en")) {
    yourImageViewID.setImageResource(R.drawable.english_image);
}
```

In both ways, `yourImageViewID` is an `ImageView`, Don't forget to add 3 images to your assets, one for the Arabic language, another one for the English language, and a third one for other languages ( will be used if device language isn't Arabic or English ), also add more images if you want to add more languages to your application

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding each picture to a different locale version within `res\drawable`. Both versions of pictures must have the same name in order to allow Android system to pick the appropriate picture when checking the device language.

In your example your locales are English & Arabic, so you need to have two folders:

- `\app\src\main\res\drawable-ar\myPicture.png` << Arabic version
- `\app\src\main\res\drawable-en\myPicture.png` <<< English version

Both pictures have the same name but they are different in content as you need.